# Llenar input desde componente en angular 10

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de llenar un input con lo que viene en response cuando el usuario teclea su código postal. Estoy usando la API de sepomex.

Puedo llenar el select para que se muestren todas las colonias, pero cuando quiero que se llene el input, ahi es donde ya no se que tengo que hacer

en mi componente obtengo la respuesta de la api de la siguiente manera

```
    onChangeEvent(event: any){
      this._clientService.getZipCode(event.target.value).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.zipData = response;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
        }
      );
}
```

Asi es como devulve el objeto

```
[
    {
        "error": false,
        "code_error": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "response": {
            "cp": "09810",
            "asentamiento": "Minerva",
            "tipo_asentamiento": "Colonia",
            "municipio": "Iztapalapa",
            "estado": "Ciudad de México",
            "ciudad": "Ciudad de México",
            "pais": "México"
        }
    },
    {
        "error": false,
        "code_error": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "response": {
            "cp": "09810",
            "asentamiento": "Granjas Esmeralda",
            "tipo_asentamiento": "Colonia",
            "municipio": "Iztapalapa",
            "estado": "Ciudad de México",
            "ciudad": "Ciudad de México",
            "pais": "México"
        }
    },
    {
        "error": false,
        "code_error": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "response": {
            "cp": "09810",
            "asentamiento": "Los Cipreses",
            "tipo_asentamiento": "Colonia",
            "municipio": "Iztapalapa",
            "estado": "Ciudad de México",
            "ciudad": "Ciudad de México",
            "pais": "México"
        }
    },
    {
        "error": false,
        "code_error": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "response": {
            "cp": "09810",
            "asentamiento": "Progreso del Sur",
            "tipo_asentamiento": "Colonia",
            "municipio": "Iztapalapa",
            "estado": "Ciudad de México",
            "ciudad": "Ciudad de México",
            "pais": "México"
        }
    }
]
```

Y mi input esta de la siguiente manera

```
<input type="text" value="algo" class="form-control" name="municipio" #municipio="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="client.municipio" required readonly>
```

Como o que es lo que tengo que hacer para llenar ese input con el nombre del municipio?

Answer (score 1):

```
response => {
     console.log(response);
     this.zipData = response;

     // response es un arreglo y cada objeto del arreglo tiene el mismo municipio
     // así que se puede tomar el primer elemento del arreglo
     // acceder a su propiedad response y luego a municipio
     // se usa el operador ? para que no falle en caso el arreglo esté vacío
     // y el municipio se asigna a la propiedad municipio del objeto client
     this.client.municipio = response[0]?.response.municipio;
}
```

Comment: oh, ya entiendo, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como mejor respuesta para que otros usuarios puedan encontrarla.